# Chrome Extension unable to send message from background to content script successfully

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage, content-script

I am trying to create an extension that, in the background script, opens a specified URL, and then sends a message to said tab that was opened in the content script side, but I am getting an error and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

background.js

```
let targetTab = "http://google.com"

main();

function main() {
  let active = true;
  let tabId = null;
  let tabUrl = null;
  if (active) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: targetTab,
    }, (tab) => {
      console.log("Tab ID Generated: " + tab.id);
      tabId = tab.id;

      chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
        tabs.forEach(tab => {
          console.log(tab.url);
          if (tab.url !== targetTab) {
            chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
          }
        })
        console.log("Tab ID Sent: " + tabId);
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
          tabId,
          tabUrl, 
        }, (response) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        })
      })
    })
  }
}
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        }
        console.log("Got Message");
        sendResponse({message: "hi to you"});
    });
```

Comment: When the tab is created it hasn't yet started to load anything so you need to wait for that by using a temporary chrome.tabs.onUpdated listener.

Comment: Please post the error message...."but I am getting an error"